# Как сделать чтобы бот мог делать несколько вещей одновременно? Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord

Мне нужно чтобы бот мог допустим изменять постоянно название сервера, но тогда я не могу использовать мои команды которые отправляются в текстовый канал.
Как сделать так, чтобы бот мог делать "несколько вещей одновременно"?
Если нужна какая-то часть кода, скажите какая, я просто не понимаю что может помочь понять идею.
Единственное что может помочь

```
client.Log += Log;
client.MessageReceived += HandleCommandAsync;
client.UserJoined += UserJoined;
client.GuildAvailable += Change_Server_Name;
```

Comment: `но тогда я не могу использовать мои команды` - так не загружайте обработчик событий, сделайте отдельную `async` команду и пусть фоном крутит нужный код. Вообще, если вы сделали все правильно, по документации, с использованием DI контейнеров и прочих прелестей, то это делается очень просто при помощи [BackgroundService](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice), достаточно сделать класс, унаследовать от `BackgroundService`, ну и зарегистрировать `.Services.AddHostedService<..>();`.

Comment: А можно ли сделать это каким-то еще способ? Первый вариант не очень вписывается в контекст моего проекта, а второй для меня довольно сложный и не понятный.
Если по другому никак, то сделаю вторым вариантом. Просто хотелось бы в начале проекта использовать как можно меньше сторонних возможностей так сказать.

Comment: Прекращайте уже искать легкого решения поставленных задач) Я вам сказал 2 основных способа, 1 - асинхронная задача. 2 - `BackgroundService`. Все это возможности языка, которые надо знать, а не искать альтернатив. Вообще, если вы не знаете языка программирования, на котором вы работаете, то зачем тогда взяли такой сложный проект, как бот? Начните с базового, напишите что-то простое для начала, то, с чем справитесь, а уж потом лезьте в такие сложные задачи, как боты. Discord.net основан полностью на асинхронном программирование, там все на `Task`'ах, как можно работать без понимания их?

Comment: Я просто иногда ленивый)
Я делал несколько консольных и winforms приложений где использовал что-то новое и не понятное, но тут это пока просто фан проект для себя, и хотелось бы для начала сделать просто чтобы работало, а потом усложнять.
Я понимаю что нужно изучать новое, и мне это нравится, но пока я не знаю будет ли это работать так, как я хочу, хотелось бы сделать быстрее и проще.
На данный момент хочется просто знать, есть ли более простой вариант чтобы сделать это. Если нет, то начну изучение ваших вариантов.

Comment: `просто чтобы работало, а потом усложнять` - я по раз 20 могу с нуля переписать свои домашние проекты, это нормальная практика для изучения чего либо, ведь написав по новой, с новыми знаниями, с набитыми старыми шишками проект становиться лучше, намного лучше. Так что не ленитесь, а просто делайте, не просто "сделаю ерунду, чтоб тупо работало", а именно пробуйте сделать правильно, сразу. Не получиться, хер с ним, перепишете потом если надо будет по уму. `есть ли более простой вариант` - я вам уже сказал, у вас только 2 варианта, синхронным способом вы не сделаете фоновые задачи!